# The edge case of an edge case: Vapor emissions of the descaling agent Sulfamic acid

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry, redox, physical-organic-chemistry

I am wondering about the following scenario:

What happens if ready bought sulfamic acid descaling (usually 15% cont. + $\ce{H2O}$) is vaporized or at least steam develops while very briefly descaling the steam wand of an espresso machine? Is there any real danger to the respiratory system with this acid in a liquid solution, even if it is already diluted? When would $\ce{SO2}$ or sulfuric acid be produced?

The material safety sheet does not warn of any real dangers if the solution becomes airborne. Pure sulfamic acid can produced $\ce{SO2}$ around 300 °C but while descaling its mixed with water.

A possible product through hydrolysis seems to be ammonium bisulfate, which in turn can thermally decompose above 120 °C to sulfur dioxides.

How much harmful $\ce{SO2}$ can there even be produced if we are only starting out with an already diluted solution and we are looking at two different reactions with additional byproducts. $\ce{SO2}$ furthermore reacts in water(vapor) to sulfuric acid which has a much higher density than air and also has a much higher boiling point than water. Is there even enough "left" for a meaningful amount of anything dangerous to be created?

I admit my problem is sadly further amplified by the fact, that the concerning espresso machine has a steam generator(circulation heater) which probably runs hotter than the regular ~140°C of an espresso machine boiler.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, sulfamic acid $\ce{NH2SO3H}$ is decomposed at about $200°$C in $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{SO3}$, which produces immediately ammonium bisulfate $\ce{NH4HSO4}$ with atmospheric water. And sulfamic acid is very soluble in water : one part acid in $2$ parts water at $100°$C.

As a consequence, you do not risk any absorption when heating solutions before $200°$C. And at higher temperatures, you will probably never get to the dangerous limit of $4$ g/m3, specially with espresso machines. All you risk is being touched by micro bubbles of ammonium bisulfate solutions